# Undefined reference error in C++ code

Tags: c++, compilation

Hello I am getting this Error when I am compiling my code:

```
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xfc): undefined reference to `CMyMath::melFilterBank(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, int, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/main.elf] Error 1
```

my .h file:

```
#ifndef _MYMATH_H_
#define _MYMATH_H_
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <complex> 
class CMyMath
{
    public:
        CMyMath();  
        ~CMyMath();
        std::vector<double> melFilterBank(std::vector<double> signal, int frequency, int band_num, int coef_num);
};
#endif
```

my .cpp file:

```
#include "MyMath.h"    
CMyMath::CMyMath()
{
    printf("constructor called\n");
}   
CMyMath::~CMyMath()
{
    printf("destructor called\n");
}
std::vector<double> melFilterBank(std::vector<double> ourSignal, int frequency, int bandNum, int coefNum)
{
    std::vector<double> output; //ck in matlab code
    /*
    DO SOME STUFF
    */
    return output;
}
```

main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include "MyMath.h"

int main()
{
    class CMyMath a;
    std::vector<double> mel {0.0000001,0.0000005,0.0000004,0.0000005};
    a.melFilterBank(mel,8000,6,5);
    return 0;
}
```

What do you think where should be a mistake? I am new in C++ and I have really no idea what`s wrong. What do you suggest?

Comment: `std::vector<double> melFilterBank` is missing the class qualifier `CMyMath::`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition (in the `.cpp` file) needs to specify that you're defining the member function, not a separate non-member function:

```
std::vector<double> CMyMath::melFilterBank(std::vector<double> ourSignal, int frequency, int bandNum, int coefNum)
                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<double> CMyMath :: melFilterBank(std::vector<double> ourSignal, int frequency, int bandNum, int coefNum)
```

Member Funtion while defining needs to be prefixed with class name.